# Ideal adsense ad unit size for a 240x320 mobile screen

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, screen-size

Currently I use only the 300x250 and 160x600 ad units on my mobile site. Those work well for most screen sizes on my mobile site. When I did some research, a mobile device with size 240x320 pixels exists and I currently own a phone with that screen resolution.

Right now, I can potentially use 160x600 ad unit, but I also want another square ad unit to fit within the 240x320 pixel space without forcing the user to side-scroll to see everything and ideally without filling up the whole screen.

I'm going against the responsive ad unit because I want to measure income from ads and use the sizes that work best both for my site and the advertisers, and for the small 240x320 pixel screen.

Also on my mobile site, I have some pages that lists thumbnails that are the size of 96x64 pixels and I feel I will need to shrink the ad unit to accomodate for those as well as margins around the ad unit and thumbnails. I might even have to shrink the thumbnails themselves.

So my question is what is the best fixed ad unit size that advertisers love best that can generate me the most profit that I can fit on a 240x320 screen without violating adsense policies?